# converting javascript to jquery function not correctly working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to convert a small script from javascript to jquery, but I don't know where I should be putting the [i] in jquery?. I am nearly there, I just need someone to point out where I have gone wrong.

This script expands a search input when focused, if the input contains any values, it retains it's expanded state, or else if the entry is removed and clicks elsewhere, it will snap back.

Here is the javascript:

```
const searchInput = document.querySelectorAll('.search');
for (i = 0; i < searchInput.length; ++i) {
    searchInput[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        if(this.value == '') {
            this.classList.remove('not-empty')
        } else {
            this.classList.add('not-empty')
        }
     });
}
```

and converting to jquery:

```
var $searchInput = $(".search");
for (i = 0; i < $searchInput.length; ++i) {
    $searchInput.on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).value == "") {
            $(this).removeClass("not-empty");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("not-empty");
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: here is an example I tried out, but I think I have it incorrectly: var $searchInput = $(".control__input--search");
 $searchInput.each(function () {
  $searchInput.on("change", function () {
  if ($(this).value == "") {
   $(this).removeClass("is-not-empty");
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("is-not-empty");
  }
 });
});

Comment: Im still not sure how to include the .on and .change methods into this script

Comment: Okay, so this is what I came up with, but its still not working :/                                                      var $searchInput = $(".control__input--search");
$searchInput.each(function () {
 $searchInput.on("change", function () {
  if ($(this).value == "") {
   $(this).removeClass("is-not-empty");
  } else {
   $(this).addClass("is-not-empty");
  }
 });
});

Answer (score 2):

Note the key benefit of jQuery that it works on *collections* of elements: methods such as `.on` automatically loop over the collection, so you don't need any more than this:

```
$('.search').on("change", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('not-empty', this.value != "");
});
```

This adds a change event listener for each of the `.search` elements. I've used `classList.toggle` as it accepts a second argument telling it whether to add or remove the class, so the `if` statement isn't needed either.

Comment: ahh, noted. Thank you for helping and making it clearer for me. Much appreciated ;)